# WMI with delphi

Tags: delphi

I've been working on a project which would read the temperature of the CPU.
Unfortunately I'm getting a conversion error. The whole thing compiles without a problem. But when I actually try to execute the code it gives me this error:
"Could not convert variant of type (Dispatch) into type (String)"

I'm not actually trying to get the Temp, On this bit I'm just looking if the way this is coded works. Temp part is going to be added later on...

The particular code:

```
    unit Unit3;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,         Forms,
      Dialogs, Menus, ExtCtrls, jpeg, WbemScripting_TLB, StdCtrls;

    type
      TForm3 = class(TForm)
        MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
        F1: TMenuItem;
        Quit1: TMenuItem;
        Help1: TMenuItem;
        Programms1: TMenuItem;
        CalCulator1: TMenuItem;
        Browser1: TMenuItem;
        emperature1: TMenuItem;
        WallPad1: TMenuItem;
        MediaPlayer1: TMenuItem;
        Image1: TImage;
        Image2: TImage;
        Load1: TMenuItem;
        Background1: TMenuItem;
        Label1: TLabel;
        Button1: TButton;
        procedure CalCulator1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Image1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Browser1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
        procedure MediaPlayer1Click(Sender: TObject);
        procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form3: TForm3;
    WMIServices: ISWbemServices;
      Root       : ISWbemObjectSet;
      Item       : Variant;
      I          : Integer;

    implementation

    uses Unit4, Unit2, Unit5;

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm3.Browser1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
     Form2.Show;
    end;

    procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    WMIServices := CoSWbemLocator.Create.ConnectServer('.', 'root\cimv2','', '', '',         '', 0, nil);
      Root  := WMIServices.ExecQuery('Select DeviceID FROM         Win32_TemperatureProbe','WQL', 0, nil);
      Label1.caption := VarToStr(Root)
    end;

    procedure TForm3.CalCulator1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    form4.show;
    end;

    procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    image1.bringtofront
    end;

    procedure TForm3.Image1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    Form4.show;
    end;

    procedure TForm3.MediaPlayer1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    form5.show;
    end;


    end.
```

I'm assuming the solution is going to be quite simple, yet I can't see it...

The error is created on this bit

```
    Label1.caption := VarToStr(Root)
```

Comment: The `ExecQuery` method returns object set, not a string.

Comment: Once again, you need to spend some time reviewing the sample code you got with MagWMI, which shows you **exactly** how to do things. You clearly can't turn `Dispatch` into `string`, because `Dispatch` is an interface for reaching other things. You have a comprehensive, detailed example available to you that Angus wrote for MagWMI - I don't understand why you won't spend some time actually looking at it so you'll learn something. It would be much faster (and easier) than posting here and waiting.

Comment: You are right, unfortunately I don't know what I'm looking for. Which makes learning it quite hard.

Comment: That error message, along with the code which raises it, is extremely clear what to look for.

Comment: @Jerry, not so extremely. It took me a few minutes to find out how to get a value from that object set (with the type library and MSDN in front of me). And then came up RRUZ and told me about an XP enumeration issue that I did not even consider.

Comment: You guys have to understand that I'm a mere 16 years old, in secondary school doing IT classes that started with "Start coding", we had no documentation, nobody to tell us what everything is called. I'm basically trying to make my way through a jungle of Jargon I don't understand very well. I've done a little CSharp (which clarifies my name) And already made a project to read temps. where all I needed was to add "Uses windows.diagnostics" to make sure i could read the temp.

To put it in short. 'I know nothing'

Comment: Ok. let me link you one more time to [`RRUZ' blog post`](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/be-careful-when-you-import-the-microsoft-wmiscripting-library/) where you can find a complete example of what to do (at the end of the post). You just replace the WQL (the query you execute) with your own one. Instead of the `Writeln` you use output of your choice (as you are not developing a console application). And instead of `SWbemPropertySet.Item('SerialNumber', 0).Get_Value` you access `SWbemPropertySet.Item('DeviceID', 0).Get_Value`. It's really as easy as that.

Comment: Thank you for linking me again.

However it raises an error

"[Pascal Error] Unit3.pas(62): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IEnumVariant'"

Could this be due to not being able to properly import the WbemScripting file, from windows?

Comment: No. That is caused by the missing reference to unit file. `IEnumVariant` is declared in the `ActiveX` unit, so add `ActiveX` to your `uses` clause. Even this is shown in that example.

Comment: Allright, I did as you said, it compiles without errors now, yet it still does not work. When I click the button. Nothing happens to the Label.

Code: http://pastebin.com/eCXJSEfs

Comment: That code looks fine (don't know how about the type library that you use). But it might well be because the query doesn't return any row. A WQL query may return 0, or more *rows* into a resultset, hence there is that enumeration (which would overwrite you that label caption in case there is more than one row, btw.). For me it returns 0 rows on my laptop even though it's having CPU temperature sensors (Windows 7). I don't know anything about the `Win32_TemperatureProbe` class, so I'm afraid I'm out of help here.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394493(v=vs.85).aspx

I don't know if you are, but if you are using the test .exe from Mag Sys, then remove the space behind the Win32-TemperatureProbe, that is why it is not returning anything. Had the same Issue

I will try a different Query though

Comment: Turns out, everything is working now...

However there is no temp value. Or at least, the one that should be the Temp Value, returns a null...

Comment: @CSharp Sounds like you may need to ask a new question then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Before continuing on this path maybe you should read the documentation [Win32_TemperatureProbe class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In the header you can read:
"Most of the information That the Win32_TemperatureProbe WMI class Provides you eat from SMBIOS. Real-time readings for the CurrentReading property can not be Retrieved from SMBIOS tables. For this reason, **current implementations of WMI do not populate the CurrentReading property**. The CurrentReading property's Presence is reserved for future use."

if you want to use WMI correctly, you can find much information on [the website of Rodrigo Ruz](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/?s=wmi) or [on my website](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?s=wmi) including samples and specific components to WMI ([GLibWMI on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/)).

There is an interesting project (opensource) in http://openhardwaremonitor.org to access hardware properties (including the ones you need). Check it out.

[image]

A greeting.